# Can I send a Text file using the Audio Jack of the Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, pi-3, audio, data-transfer

I am pretty new to working with the Pi. My project requires me to send data in ASCII format through the 3.5mm Audio Jack of the Raspberry Pi, which would, in turn, be taken up by some other device.
Also, the language I'm using if Python 2.7

If I can, HOW?

Comment: It might help to explain this requirement (using the audio jack) and a little more about your project and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Checkout this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/using-the-audio-jack-as-data-interface-on-android-systems

Comment: Sounds like a school exercise to me.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I am using the Pi-3 to record temperature consistently. In the project, there is a requirement wherein I have to send the temperature data in ASCII format to a Telemetry device that will be connected to the Raspberry-Pi using the Audio Jack.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Any leads?

Comment: @rodripf I went through it, but it sends over data in the form of audio signals, whereas according to my project's requirement, it should be in ASCII format. So that, the telemetry device receiving that data can directly use it.

Comment: @joan Any leads would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are you building that has this crazy requirement? Is this a school project?

Comment: Are you sure this is audio over phone connector instead of RS232 over phone connector ?

Comment: We'll need details of the telemetry device you need to write to. Some of them use serial over audio jacks, but they're not audio signals. So until you describe what you're connecting to, none of us can answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are several solutions:

- quietnet -> https://github.com/Katee/quietnet
- minimodem -> http://www.whence.com/minimodem/
- morse code

Comment: Morse code ! Then use another Pi to decode. If you wanna spice things up try the Enigma Cipher!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.

Strictly speaking it is not impossible. It would be possible to emulate a modem protocol, but this would require a demod at the other end.

Comment: that is the catch, where I'm stuck. The other end can not perform any modifications to the data it receives and hence should be in ASCII format. Even pure ASCII text would do instead of a file.

Comment: ASCII is a character encoding standard, not a transmission protocol. Does your receiving device define a protocol that it is expecting to communicate using?

Comment: Yea.. You may be thinking of sending actual binary using the Audio Jack.. (that is what the iPhone had blocked recently) No.. The audio jack sits behind and Audio synthesizer. You cannot pump binary data to it and expect that to do down the audio cable.. because that jack outputs analog data. Look at the Morse code suggestion! One Pi encodes ASCII into Morse while the other listens and decodes it! You know.. like modernised telegram messages. You cant use that Jack for binary streaming unless you create an analog way to stream binary (aka MoDem) ohh-